# SQL How to select rows based on values from multiple rows

Tags: sql, select, inner-join, aggregate-functions, having-clause

Hi I ran into a problem regarding the following tables

```sql
       CREATE TABLE BOOKS ( 
          Title varchar(255),
          Year INT,
          Type ENUM("Horror", "Fantasy"),
          Pages INT,
          PRIMARY KEY (Title, Year)
        );
        
        CREATE TABLE AUTHORS(
          Title varchar(255), 
          Year INT, 
          PlaceOfBirth varchar(255), 
          AuthorName varchar(255),
          PRIMARY KEY (Title, Year, PlaceOfBirth ),
          FOREIGN KEY (Title, Year) REFERENCES BOOKS(Title, Year)
        );
```

Now i want to query all Authors who only have horror books with 40 pages and more.

```sql
SELECT a.AuthorName, b.Pages FROM AUTHORS a INNER JOIN BOOKS b ON a.Title=b.Title AND a.Year=b.Year
WHERE  b.Type="Horror" AND b.Pages > 40
```

The problem is now I get those authors which have written horror books with more than 40 pages but they could also have horror books with less than 40 pages. I Want those Authors which only wrote horror books that are 40 pages or longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the name of authors that have written at least one horror book and whose all such books have more than 40 pages, you can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select a.authorname
from authors a 
inner join books b on a.title = b.title and a.year = b.year
where b.type = 'Horror' 
group by a.authorname
having min(b.pages) > 40
```

Comment: I was considering that but mysql is throwing an error when i try it  Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column